# Google Sheets: How can I use LEFT(Col1,3) function in query string?

Tags: google-sheets

I like to extract the 3-left characters of a query column

this does not work

`=QUERY(data,"select LEFT(Col1,3)",1)`

Can someone help me  how can I get extract only the first 3 letters of a query column?

Thanks.

DATA:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| abc123 | Cell 2 |
| cde456 | Cell 4 |
| efg789 | Cell 4 |

Expected Result

| Column A |
| --- |
| abc |
| cde |
| efg |

However, I get the following error:

Formula parse error.

Comment: Can you maybe share a *screenshot* showcasing your input & output you're able to obtain using the `first-format formula`?!

Comment: rock:

You are right - it does not work either. 
Is there a way to get the left(Col1, 3) to work inside a query string?

Comment: maybe we could look into alternative solutions. If interested you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Rock:  thank you for your help.   Below is a sheet with some sample data (only a couple of lines-actual data has over 5,000 lines)

Test Data Sheet = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iRGbLsuMgsVrwW31K2XvUIRzSTzooNyIG99Fd0J98IE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

*Guessing this is your expected output based on your [other(new) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78176824/5479575) here:*

```js
=map(E3:E,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,mid(Σ,find("-",Σ)+1,9^9))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that works. (Question:  What is the 9^9 for?)

Comment: its just set to an arbitrary high number prompting *mid()* to pick up any number of characters available after **"-"**