# Google Sheets: How to use left() inside an array formula?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to remove the first 3 char from D using

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(C3:C) < 1, "", LEFT(D3:D, FIND("-", D3:D) - 1)))`

**Data:**

| _ | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/14/24 | 2k21053.11-1230-abdc | 111-Clerical |  |
| 2 | 3/14/24 | 2k21053.11-1230-cde | 123-Construction |  |
| 3 | 3/14/24 | 2k21053.11-1230-efg | 111-Clerical |  |
| 4 | 3/14/24 | 2k21053.11-1230-abc | 123-Construction Admin-Eng |  |

**Expected Results: **
|Task |
| -------- |
|Clerical|
|Construction|
|Clerical|
|Construction Admin-Eng|

However I get the following error:

`Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (3).`

When I use this it works as expected on one line at a time.

```
=left(D3,find("-",D3)-1)
```

Comment: in which cell are you entering the formula?

Comment: Z:   

Formula goes in Cell E1.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are entering the formula in E1 then I don't see why it would give you that error. That error generally means that you entered the formula below row 3. Please share a sample sheet where you reproduce the issue.

Comment: Z.  - thank you for your comment.   i was suggested to use a lambda and map combination for this issue as follows:   =map(E3:E,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,mid(Σ,find("-",Σ)+1,9^9))))